# My variable does not include all copied text using sublime.get_clipboard() sublime text plugin

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I'm trying to create a sublime text 3 plugin that copies code from files like .html, .css, .js & .php and then pastes it in a txt document.

My problem is that sometimes when I copy code from a document with a lot of code and paste it into a text document, some of the code disappears.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

def save_code(file):
    sublime.active_window().active_view().set_status("","Your file is
    saved inside _templates " + file + "!")
    text_file = open("path_to_file/_templates"+file, "w")
    my_copy = str(sublime.get_clipboard())
    text_file.write("%s" % my_copy)
    text_file.close()
class MycopypasteCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.window().show_input_panel("Add
        filename:","",save_code,None,None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. My problem was that when I copied text that contained "Åäö", text_file.write("%s" % my_copy) couldn't write to file. My solution was simpel. Just need 2 add encoding="utf-8" at the end of open("path_to_file, "w", open("path_to_file/_templates"+file, "w", encoding="utf-8")